# Path to use in web.config when deploying Meteorjs

Tags: azure, deployment, meteor, config, nitrousio

Trying to deploy a meteorjs app to Azure, everything looks configured correctly except I'm not sure what to point to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation batch="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
              <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I do not have a `server.js`. I am deploying this from nitrous.io, where the app works as expected. Do I need to add a server.js file, and if so, what should be the content? Otherwise, what file is appropriate to point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builded Meteor Application on output has `main.js` in root folder of your application, you should point your web server onto this file.

In rewrite rule use regular expression:

```
<match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
```

So your config file will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation batch="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also do not forget to set ENV variables for builded Meteor: `MONGO_URL`, `ROOT_URL` (domain with protocol, like: http://my.site), `MAIL_URL`, etc.